# How to shorten space between x-axis labels in vue-apex chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, apexcharts

I have a simple chart created using vue-apex charts that displays the amount of an asset over time, it works great, but the x-axis displays my data with a lot of distance like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctucl.jpg

How can I reduce the distance between the x-axis items like here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh5Ha.jpg

here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="balance-card-container">
    <div class="s">
      <md-card class="balance-card">
        <md-card-header>
          <div class="md-title title">{{ title }}</div>
        </md-card-header>
        <md-card-content>
          <p class="number-p">2345</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>


      <md-card class="second-card">
              <!-- <h2 class="users">Assessments summary</h2> -->
              <div class="chart-wrapper">
                  <apexchart width="900" height="200" type="line" :options="options" :series="series"></apexchart>
              </div>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../variables.scss";


.balance-card {
  border-radius: 14px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px -6px rgba(221, 243, 255, 0.6) !important;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: $casal;
}

.number-p {
  text-align: center;

  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
  color: $casal;
}

.s {
  display: flex;
}

.second-card {
  width: 900px !important;
}

.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BalanceCard",
  props: ["title"],
  data() {
      return {
      options: {
        chart: {
          id: 'vuechart-example'
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'series-1',
        data: [10000, 5000, 1000]
      }]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```